# Magento connect to database from a module?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, extensions

I am just a newbie in magento. Currently I am developing a small extension. In that I have put some ajax request. So for that I need to connect to the database in that file. I want to fetch the data from the table named as magento_storeinfo. So can someone kindly tell me how to connect to the database and the table?

I had tried this(hardcoding) for connecting to the database

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$uname = 'root';
$pwd = 'root';
$db = 'magento_storeinfo';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db);
define("ROOTPATH","FOLDER/");
error_reporting(5);
?>
```

But with this when I am doing ajax request it is showing No database selected. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please check out [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) although it outlines how to make a grid/edit section in the backend as well it contains also the information on how to set up a connection to a custom table using `Magento Resource Models`.

If you don't need the adminhtml (backend) section just skip the part with the adminhtml `controller` and `blocks`.

The main part that allows you to read and write to and from the database is this part in the config.xml and that actual model classes to go along with that

```
<config>
   [...]
   <global>
      [...]
      <models>
         <[module]>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>[module]_mysql4</resourceModel>
         </[module]>
         <[module]_mysql4>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
               <[module]>
                  <table>[module]</table>
               </[module]>
            </entities>
         </[module]_mysql4>
      </models>
      <resources>
         <[module]_setup>
            <setup>
               <module>[Namespace]_[Module]</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
               <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
         </[module]_setup>
         <[module]_write>
            <connection>
               <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
         </[module]_write>
         <[module]_read>
            <connection>
               <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
         </[module]_read>
      </resources>
      [...]
   </global>
   [...]
</config>
```

Once you've set that up you can go ahead and create a controller that handles the ajax call. In this controller we'll have a method in which the database query is executed and the results outputted

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function responseAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

        // using the collection resource to retrieve the first item from that collection and it's data
        $collection = Mage::getModel('[namespace]/[module]')->getCollection();
        $data = $collection->getFirstItem()->getData();

        // using a query to get the data
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        $resource = $write->query("SELECT * `magento_storeinfo` LIMIT 1");
        $data = $resource->fetch();

        $this->getResponse()
                ->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($data))
                ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now we can call this Ajax controller using the url `http://domain.com/[module]/ajax/response/`

Comment: yes with module's config.xml I have created the database table with read and write, but I have an ajax request ad in that ajax file I want to connect  to the database table . So how to connect to the database in that file?

Comment: updated my question with some more info on how to use this connection :)